# Как записать в список вводимый текст пользователя через handler?

Tags: python, telebot

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой при записи сообщения пользователя в список.Мне нужно записать вводимый id пользователя в список accept_user_id через handler.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['add_user'])
def add_user(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите id пользователя✅")
    user_id = message.text
    accept_user_id.append(user_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "id внесён✅")
    exit(add_user)
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Список где-нибудь объявляется за пределами хендлера? А как ты будешь его разграничивать между пользователями? Вообще, для чего список? Не понимаю

Comment: Список прописан до хандлера и нужен чтобы проверять находится ли id пользователя в этом списке.

Comment: И в чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение нужно использовать bot.register_next_step_handler которая передаёт переменную в другую функцию.

```
def add_user(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите id пользователя✅")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, add_user_help)

def add_user_help(message):
    user_id = message.text
    accept_user_id.append(user_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, accept_user_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, user_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "id внесён✅")
    exit(add_user)
```

Comment: Не добавляйте код на Python через кнопку "Фрагмент кода HTML/JS/CSS". Кнопка для выделения фрагментов кода не из этого списка немного левее.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй использовать state, чтобы забирать информацию, и потом делать с ней, все что хочешь
машина состояний часто используется для регистрации пользователей, то есть можно прописать столько шагов, сколько захочешь

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]